# How can I assign a different ID for each collapsible element with a certain class and add that ID to the href of the buttons so they can toggle?

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Bit of a long winded question - I'm basically using the toggle function from Bootstrap to show and hide a text box when clicking a button.  My issue is, the text box and button is used for each item in a list which is dynamically loaded so I can't assign IDs via HTML as usual.

How can I generate a different ID for each text box and add that ID to each text box's button's href tag?

Here's my code of the text box and button (which sits inside an li tag along with some other information which gets generated for each item in the list):

```
<div id="comment-container">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="add-comment" class="btn btn-primary add-comment"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><span>Add Comment</span></a>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.CurrentStage.Responses[i].Comment, new { @class = "form-control comment collapse", rows = 3, placeholder = "Enter a comment to accompany your response here:" })
</div>
```

I've played about with some snippets of jquery, but nothing's quite worked so far.

Here's how it should look when it works:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzSXM.jpg)

Comment: Why do you need it to be random? Can't you just use the index? I mean that you are loading a list of N elements, then you iterate over it from 1 to Nand use there indexes and create IDs like "#bt1", "#bt2", "#bt3" an so on.

Comment: Use a static counter and just increment.

Comment: You don't need ID for this ... use `$(this).next()`... or `$(this).closest('.comment-container').find('textarea`)`

Comment: Yeah sorry, bad choice of words - it doesn't need to be random, just different for each - but I believe I need an ID for the href to use for the toggle function to work.

Comment: How are you loading them dynamically? There are plenty of ways that you can assign different values to them, but they all depend on the method they're being added to the DOM.

Comment: It's pulled from a database and into a model (says the developer I'm working with - I know even less about that voodoo).  I know how I can assign a value to any of those elements or classes, I just don't know how to assign a different value to each of them and also assign it to the href of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need to assign a random id to the textbox to handle this. You may use relative jQuery selectors to gt access to the textarea which belongs in the same parent container.

Looks like you have hard coded the `Id` value of the container div. When you run your code, your loop will produce multiple div's with same Id value.You cannot have same Id for more than one element.  So remove the Id of the outer div and give a css class which we will use for our jQuery selector later.

```
<div class="comment-item-container">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="add-comment" 
        class="btn btn-primary add-comment"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                                                        <span>Add Comment</span></a>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.CurrentStage.Responses[i].Comment, 
      new { @class = "form-control comment collapse", rows = 3,
                       placeholder = "Enter a comment to accompany your response here:" })
</div>
```

Now in your javascript listen to the click event on the link, use the `closest()` method to get to the outer container div then use `find()` method to get access to the text area.

```
$(function(){

  $("a.add-comment").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

      var outerDiv = $(this).closest(".comment-item-container");  //get outer div

      var txtArea = outerDiv.find("textarea");   // find the textarea(s) in the outer div

      txtArea.toggle();  //change visibility of the result textareas
  });

});
```

Thanks to jQuery chaining. We can use a one liner to replace all three lines.

```
$(function(){

  $("a.add-comment").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest(".comment-item-container").find("textarea").toggle();
  });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/komade/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  Sorry, that doesn't seem to work properly.  By default, all textareas are set to display:none because of the collapse class.  When I click the button with your code it tells the textarea to display:none as well, and that doesn't seem to toggle when the button is clicked again.  At least the buttons are only targeting their designated textareas.

Comment: Without the collapse class though, it says display:block - but again, doesn't toggle.  I think we're close here though.

Comment: Totally works for me. See here http://jsbin.com/komade/edit?html,css,js,console,output . If your markup or css definitions are different, can you share it in a js fiddle ?